# unexpected end kend ruby piglatin program

Tags: ruby

I needed to write a program that converts normal speech into pig latin. I wrote

```
def translate(*string)
  word = []
  word_string = []
  s = []
  i = 0
  a = nil


  #enters input from user into individual arrays spots
  #removes spaces
  string[0].scan(/\w+/).each { |x| word << x }

  #goes through each word and does operation
  while i < word.count
     word[i].scan(/./) { |x| word_string << x }

     #checks if starts with vowel
     if word_string[0].include?("aeiou" || "AEIOU")
       word_string = word_string << "ay"
       s[i] << word_string.join('')

     #checks if starts with Qu or qu  
     elsif word_string[0] + word_string[1] == "qu" || word_string[0] + word_string[1] == "Qu"
       word_string.delete_at(0) && word_string.delete_at(1)
       word_string << "quay"
       s[i] = word_string.join('')

     #checks if starts with 3 consonants   
     unless (word_string[0] + word_string[1] + word_string[2]).include?("aeiou") 
       a = word_string[0] + word_string[1] + word_string[2]
       word_string.delete_at(0) && word_string.delete_at(1) && word_string.delete_at(2)
       word_string << (a + "ay")
       s[i] = word_string.join('')
       a = nil

    #checks if starts with 2 consonants   
    unless (word_string[0] + word_string[1]).include?("aeiou")
       a = word_string[0] + word_string[1]
       word_string.delete_at(0) && word_string.delete_at(1)
       word_string << (a + "ay")
       s[i] = word_string.join('')
       a = nil

   #check if starts with 1 consonants
   else
      a = word_string[0]
      word_string.delete_at(0)
      word_string << (a + "ay")
      s[i] = word_string.join('')
      a = nil
   end

  i += 1

  end
s.join(" ")
end
```

It returned to me a error saying

```
pig_latin.rb:58: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
```

I looked into the error, it means that I either missed a end somewhere or I have one too many, but I am unable to find it. I have a def end, a while end and a if end so the issue isn't there. I thought it might be somewhere in the first few linkes where I wrote the scans to sort the text originally but it doesn't seem like its there either. I need another pair of eyes to take a look, I can't find it. Also if there would be a better way to write this, please let me know.

Comment: the `if`, `elsif` and `else` should be one block. Do not mix `unless` and the rest. Use a `case` statement if multiple checks are to be performed and this will be a lot cleaner to understand and debug.

Comment: I originally wrote the unless statements as 

    'elsif (word_string[0] + word_string[1]).!include?("aeiou")'

but I did more reading and it doesn't seem like you can do that. Is there another way to write that part?

Comment: Like I said, use a `case` statement and you'd be better off. Since you ask, the `elsif` part can be written as: `elsif !((word_string[0]+word_string[1]).include?("aeiou"))`.

Comment: Also, may be that part of your logic should be: `("aeiou").include?(..)` since "ae".include?("aeiou") returns false. May be I am wrong as I did not have a look at the entire logic but you might want to have a second look into it.

Comment: Wrote this gist that has an alternative implementation: https://gist.github.com/kgrz/5432485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more how the code should look, if it was written in more of a Ruby way:

```
def translate(string)

  pig_latin = []

  words = string.split(/\W+/)

  words.each do |word|

    case word
    when /^[aeiou]/i
      pig_latin << (word + "ay")

    when /^qu/i
      word << word[0,2] << 'ay'
      pig_latin << word[2 .. -1]

    when /^[^aeiou]{3}/i
      word << word[0,3] << 'ay'
      pig_latin << word[3..-1]

    when /^[^aeiou]{2}/i
      word << word[0, 2] << 'ay'
      pig_latin << word[2 .. -1]

    else
      word << word[0] << 'ay'
      pig_latin << word[1 .. -1]
    end

  end
  pig_latin.join(' ')
end

puts translate('the rain in spain stays mainly on the plain')
=> ethay ainray inay ainspay aysstay ainlymay onay ethay ainplay
```

I'd have checked for consonants differently.

How it works is left to the reader to figure out. If this was a homework assignment, take the time to figure out how it works, because knowing what it does is important. Copying other people's work... well, this is on the internet now so anyone can search and find it, so don't plagiarize.

Comment: what does the i mean at the end of each when statement? such as when /^[^aeiou]{2}/i